# C-API register a ufunc loop against builtin ufunc

Tags: python, numpy, c-api

I am looking to build a numpy extension module which declares a new structured dtype and provides the necessary inner ufunc loops to allow [built-in math operations](https://numpy.org/neps/nep-0013-ufunc-overrides.html#list-of-operators-and-numpy-ufuncs) to be performed on it.

Following the guide on [creating your own ufunc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/c-info.ufunc-tutorial.html), I have been able to:

- Create a new `PyUFuncGenericFunction` to mock a built-in ufunc:

  ```c
  PyUFuncGenericFunction *add_uncertain = PyUFunc_FromFuncAndData(
      NULL,
      NULL,
      NULL,
      0,
      2,
      1,
      PyUFunc_None,
      "add_uncertain",
      "adds arrays of uncertain values",
      0);
  ```
- Declare the data-type, as:

  ```c
  PyObject *uncertain_double_dtype_dict = Py_BuildValue(
      "[(s, s), (s, s)]",
      "nominal", "f8", "uncertainty", "f8");
  ```
- Write an implementation of this for a specific dtype:

  ```c
  static PyObject *
  add_uncertain_double(char **args, npy_intp *dimensions, npy_intp *steps, void *data)
  {
      char *in_arr_a = args[0];
      char *in_arr_b = args[1];
      char *out_arr = args[2];

      npy_intp in_a_step = steps[0];
      npy_intp in_b_step = steps[1];
      npy_intp out_step = steps[2];

      for (npy_intp i = 0; i < dimensions[0]; i++)
      {
          double *in_a = (double *)in_arr_a;
          double *in_b = (double *)in_arr_b;
          double *out = (double *)out_arr;

          out[0] = in_a[0] + in_b[0];
          out[1] = hypot(in_a[1], in_b[1]);

          in_arr_a += in_a_step;
          out_arr += out_step;
      }
  };
  ```
- Register this function against the *mock* ufunc:

  ```c
  PyUFunc_RegisterLoopForDescr(
      add_uncertain,
      uncertain_double_dtype,
      &add_uncertain_double,
      add_uncertain_double_dtypes,
      NULL);
  ```

When exported as a module this works as intended, but requires the user to call the function via the package exported ufunc (i.e. `my_package.add_uncertain`); I would rather this implementation was available via `numpy.add`.

The language used in the [registering a ufunc loop section](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/c-info.beyond-basics.html#registering-a-ufunc-loop) of the numpy C-API docs seems to suggest that I should be able to register the ufunc loop against built-in ufuncs. To do so I believe I should pass the built-in `PyUFuncGenericFunction` to `PyUFunc_RegisterLoopForDescr`.

I would be very grateful to know if I am on the right track with this, and if so where I should look for the built-in `PyUFuncGenericFunction`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution, as contained within [the numpy rational type test](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/aeb39dfb3566e853a09082bfe9438ef118916be7/numpy/core/src/umath/_rational_tests.c#L1219), was to import `numpy` with `PyImport_Import` then get the `add` ufunc using `PyObject_GetAttrString`, at which point the new inner loop could be registered:

```c
  numpy_str = PyUnicode_FromString("numpy");
  if (!numpy_str) 
      return NULL;
  numpy = PyImport_Import(numpy_str);
  Py_DECREF(numpy_str);
  if (!numpy)
      return NULL;

  PyUFuncObject *add_ufunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(numpy, "add");
  if (!add_ufunc)
      return NULL;

  PyUFunc_RegisterLoopForDescr(
      add_ufunc,
      uncertain_double_dtype,
      &add_uncertain_double,
      add_uncertain_double_dtypes,
      NULL);
```